# How to view Gmod screenshots from other computer but the same account?

Tags: steam, garrys-mod

I have an ancient s775/DDR2 system (replaced with AM3/DDR3 pc), but it has some problems with cooling and I can't turn it on, I don't have much time to solve the problem tho. 
So, I made a big amount of screenshots on it in gmod, but I can't view them on my new pc (yeah I could just take out the hard drive from the old one and connect it to my new system, but the problem is that my psu has only 1 sata power cable (it had another cable, but got fried by optical drive)). Is there some cloud system thing in Steam that syncs not only addons, but also the screenshots?
P.S. Both systems have the same account logged in Steam.

Comment: This seems like you want to work around a lot of other issues. Why not just solve any of the issues instead of what you're asking about? Also, why can't you just upload the images?

Comment: Again, I don't have much time, I must study, go to kickboxing training, then musical school, then IT school, well, I hope you understood. I have some free only on sunday, which is enough for me. And why do you need images? I may take them, but not now, as I'm going to school in 10 mins. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I don't need images, you need them. Just go to where they are saved and upload them anywhere. Then you can download them on wherever you want to have them.

Comment: Ah, you meant uploading the screenshots? How could I not know about that.. FACEPALM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer, Steam does not have the Screenshots. Unless you've uploaded them to your profile in which case they'd be here, under Screenshots[image]

If they aren't there , the only place you'll find them is the HDD you saved them to

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess I need to take them out from the hdd. But how? I have to answer it myself. Thanks for info anyway.